# WTP - m2e not deploying transitive dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, eclipse-wtp

I have a web application which is structured in this way:

**A.jar -> B.war -> C.war**

I'm using Eclipse Juno and the **WTP version is 1.1**. The A.jar is a workspace utility project which is being included by B.war. B.war is a war project that is included by C.war as an overlay. That's [the way](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) I'm doing that:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that, I deploy the C project to the Tomcat server. That works like a charm if I manually deploy the Maven generated war to the Tomcat, because A.jar is included in *WEB-INF/lib*. However my problem comes when I let **m2e-wtp** do the deploy, because it's doing the overlay properly but not including the A transitive dependency. I tried including it as a pom, as I read somewhere around here, but I have the same result.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I'm using the newest versions of **m2e** (1.2) and **m2e-wtp** (0.16) and have my projects updated with the Maven configuration.

Is it an m2e-wtp issue or simply do I have to organize my project in other way?

---

**EDITED**

I noticed m2e-wtp configuration is stored into Eclipse's *project./settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component* file. That's how it looks for my war:

```xml
<dependent-module deploy-path="/"
    handle="module:/overlay/prj/B?includes=**/**&amp;excludes=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <dependency-type>consumes</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
<dependent-module deploy-path="/"
    handle="module:/overlay/slf/?includes=**/**&amp;excludes=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
    <dependency-type>consumes</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
```

As I can see the war dependency is set for **consume** while the jar dependencies are set for **use**.

Released m2e-wtp version 0.17 doesn't seem to fix it.

---

**EDITED (2013-08-30)**

Today I was back to the same problem. Even I have Eclipse kepler installed with the [latest stable release of WTP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/1.0.0) out of the box, this problem seems to persist. I thought it was solved, but I apparently mischeck it...

Comment: Yes. Still seeing the problem with m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP (Incubation) version 0.17.0.20130212.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not a problem of your project organization. Your issue is very similar to this m2e-wtp  [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398138).

Comment: I was expecting another kind of response, but I suposse is plugin's bug. You deserve the bounty because of the link to it.

Comment: bug has been fixed on 2015-03-05 15. I tested the snapshot m2e-wtp from http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/snapshots/mars/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Eclipse Juno and WTP Plugin problem.

I had the same problem and i solved in this way:

1. Backup your eclipse workspace and your project code
2. remove your project from eclipse (without remove the contents)
3. open a command terminal (cmd)
4. run *mvn eclipse:clean*
5. run *mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0*
6. edit your eclipse classpath file with a text editor: %PROJECT_PATH%\.classpath
7. remove all lines with attribute *kind="var"* from your *.classpath* file. For example:

> < classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5-sources.jar"/>
>
> save file & close editor.
>
> in eclipse, click on: file->Import...->Maven->import existing maven project, and import your project again
>
> Maven -> Update Project (if you want)
>
> You could see on *deployment assembly* in eclipse project properties that problem is solved and the maven dependencies are there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still have to try your solution, what I do is just include the transitive dependency depending on the profile. Anyway, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. I have an ugly workaround:

Put *all* the original war's dependencies in a separate project (type jar) and make both original war and overlay war depend on that. So for the example:

**A.jar -> B.war -> C.war**

becomes

**A.jar -> B-dependencies.jar** (new module called B-dependencies created)

**B-dependencies.jar -> B.war**

**B-dependencies.jar -> C.war**

Note that it's not specific to Tomcat; I'm using JBoss.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I do. Furthermore, I include B-dependencies.jar depending on the profile (I use it with eclipse profile and not with production one, as the problem is related with eclipse). I changed question title to unrelate it to Tomcat ;-)

Comment: The m2e-wtp founder has [a similar solution](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398138#c6) which is not working for me. Not totally solved at 1.0.1 yet.